# function was not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that displays asterisks and spaces based on their input and I've run into a compiler problem:

```
chart.cpp:24:41: error: ‘find_largest’ was not declared in this scope
  int largest = find_largest(values, size);
```

This is my code:

```
/*
 * Project 1
 * Author: Erik Ingvoldsen
 * Date: 2/1/2018
 */

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int size = 0; //initalizing "size" at 0.
const int MAX = 100; //setting max value
int values[MAX]; //100 int limit

int main(){
    int num;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        cin >> num; //allow the user to put in a number
        values[i] = num; //assigning value to the array
        if (num <= 0) {
            break; //stop if "0" or lower is entered
        }
        size++; //increase the size of array, assuming the for loop hasn't been broken
    }
    int largest = find_largest(values, size); //setting the amount of rows
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (values[i] = largest) {
            cout << "*"; //if the value of the area reachest the highest row, give a *
        } else {
            cout << "\n"; //otherwise just give a blank space
        }
        largest--; //by shrinking "largest", we move down the next row
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int find_largest(int values[], int size) {
    int largest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (values[i] > largest) { 
            largest = values[i]; //if the value of the array is bigger than the current largest it is replace
        }
    }
    return largest; //once the for loop is completed, it returns the largest number found
}
```

I really can't tell the difference between this and the function...and I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to declare it as "int largest = find_largest(values[], size);"

Comment: `if (values[i] = largest)` You probably meant `==`.

Comment: `int find_largest(int values[], int size)` is defined after it is used in the `main` you need to at least have its declaration before the `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to declare all functions before you use them. Simple way to do that is to use a prototype.

```
// prototype
int find_largest(int values[], int size);

int main(){
    ...
}

int find_largest(int values[], int size) {
    ...
}
```